# Rendering layout with ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I can't render layout with ejs, express:

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.basicAuth('username', 'password'));
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
});
```

layout.ejs is in /views folder. I render /views/home/index.ejs but it is *NOT* in layout:

```
res.render('home/index');
```

layout.ejs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/styles/site.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/styles/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your url and router code here !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In express 3, you need to add partial and layout supports separately with [express-partials](https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials)

```
npm install express-partials
```

Answer (score 12):

I use ejs-locals instead. It's a fork of ejs-partials but is actively maintained.

```
npm install ejs-locals
```

https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals

```
<% layout('boilerplate') -%>
<% script('foo.js') -%>
<% stylesheet('foo.css') -%>
<h1>I am the <%=what%> template</h1>
<% block('header', "<p>I'm in the header.</p>") -%>
<% block('footer', "<p>I'm in the footer.</p>") -%>
```

And a layout, boilerplate.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>It's <%=who%></title>
    <%-scripts%>
    <%-stylesheets%>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <%-blocks.header%>
    </header>
    <section>
      <%-body -%>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <%-blocks.footer%>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ejs-locals` is not maintained now! any other suggestions?

Comment: While not ideal, these seem to be the most viable replacements: [ejs-mate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-mate) and [express-ejs-layouts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts). ejs-mate is a fork, has more features, but wasn't updated since august 2015.